# errors with npm after purchasing a new computer

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, sass, npm-install

I have been trying to get npm up and running since purchasing a new computer. But I am getting a ton of errors when I try to install npm. I have npm installed globally. My old bootcamp created a js-generate command that creates a react js environment for you but when I try to install all the modules I need for it using npm install I get these errors and warnings. After seeing the errors I did try to install python 3 on my computer. The project is on a separate SSD from the boot drive so that might influence things. I installed python 3 on my boot drive.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFtDJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG1M3.png)

Comment: please post your error logs and how to recreate them in the question instead of posting them as a picture. 

Comment: also, according to the logs, python isn't installed on your new machine, can you confirm if python was installed in your previous one?

Comment: I installed Python on my new machine and my old one. Python 3 I followed the installer for windows for python3.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is all the code that is provided to me after I try to install NPM what would be better?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like python isnt installed on your machine, you may have to install python to remove this error. You can get the latest version of python from [the python website](https://www.python.org).

Comment: I installed python 3 after I started getting these errors. But this is being run on a second SSD separate from the boot drive. Do you think that would influence anything?